# How I can show a image from network, but if there is something wrong I want to show an image from app assets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

let's say I have this

String imageNetworkLink = someUnstableLink;

I want to be able to show that image in my flutter app if it's working, otherwise I want to show an image from my assets.

I tried using `Image.asset()` and `AssetImage()` and `Image.network()` but none of theme accepts a netork link and asset path link

I'm expecting to show either a link from network, if there is a problem, I want to show an image from asset

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I have been using the [Cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package, it has an error builder, it works great and it also has a loading builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Usage:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
     imageUrl: "http://some_image_on_the_internet.png",
     // Some widget to display while the network widget is loading
     //It could be any widget
     placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(''),
     // Some widget to display if the network image was unable to load
     // This could be because of loss of internet connection
     errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

For your usecase, You may only need to implement `imageUrl` which is required and `errorWidget`, for when something goes wrong